# Pyspark loop and add column

Tags: python, loops, pyspark

Apologies for what is probably a basic question, but I'm quite new to python and pyspark.

I have a dataframe with a single column but multiple rows, I'm trying to iterate the rows and run a sql line of code on each row and add a column with the result.
Currently I have the sql working and returning the expected result when I hard code just 1 single value, but trying to then add to it by looping through all rows in the column.

Hope that makes sense!!

Here's the code I'm using

```
%python

table = spark.read.table("my_data")
Unique_ID = table.dropDuplicates(["IDs"]).select("IDs")
Single_ID = 123456

spark.sql(f"SELECT MIN(Table1.age) AS next_number FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.age > (select Table2.age from Table2 where IDs = {Single_ID})").show()
```

So this returns the expected value for Single_ID, however Single_ID is just one of the many values that are in Unique_ID, so looking to adapt this to loop through all the values in Unique_ID

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In pyspark you never iterate the rows. You apply functions to the entire column at once. What's table1 and table2? The logic is not quite clear to me yet. If you specify, I can convert it to pyspark.